# OAuth workflow without redirect URL in QT

Tags: qt, oauth

I have a QT desktop application. I want to implement the OAuth workflow using inbuilt QT functionality. I ran the redditclient example provided by QT. This requires us to provide a redirect URL which in the example is as below:

[image]

Is there a way to get the authorization code without showing this redirect URL? As I have a desktop application, so not sure what the redirect URL would me in my case?

Comment: What service do you want to access using OAuth? I do it to show you a practical example

Comment: I want to access the documentation center of our company using my tool. If you can show me how to do it in the redditclient example, it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to use a browser or some similar means to authenticate and accept the permissions of the application. If you do not want to use the browser then you can use QWebEngineView, and to show an example I will rely on the official example of Qt [Reddit Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetworkauth-redditclient-example.html):

So modify it so you don't use QDesktopServices::openUrl() but the QWebEngineView:

**redditwrapper.h**

```cpp
// ...
private:
    QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow oauth2;
    bool permanent = false;
    QWebEngineView browser;
};
```

**redditwrapper.cpp**

```
// ...
RedditWrapper::RedditWrapper(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    auto replyHandler = new QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler(1337, this);
    oauth2.setReplyHandler(replyHandler);
    oauth2.setAuthorizationUrl(QUrl("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize"));
    oauth2.setAccessTokenUrl(QUrl("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token"));
    oauth2.setScope("identity read");

    connect(&oauth2, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::statusChanged, [=](
            QAbstractOAuth::Status status) {
        if (status == QAbstractOAuth::Status::Granted)
            emit authenticated();
    });
    oauth2.setModifyParametersFunction([&](QAbstractOAuth::Stage stage, QVariantMap *parameters) {
        if (stage == QAbstractOAuth::Stage::RequestingAuthorization && isPermanent())
            parameters->insert("duration", "permanent");
    });

    connect(&oauth2, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizeWithBrowser, [this](const QUrl & url){
        browser.resize(640, 480);
        browser.load(url);
        browser.show();
    });
    connect(&browser, &QWebEngineView::urlChanged, [replyHandler, this](const QUrl & url){
        if(url.adjusted(QUrl::RemoveQuery) == QUrl(replyHandler->callback())){
            qDebug() << url;
            browser.close();
        }
    });
}
// ...
```